# How to use JMeter's internal methods (vars.get(), etc.) in Groovy class in JSR223

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I write Groovy script in my JSR223 PreProcessor like this

```js
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

class jmeter {

   
    def parsingJSON(String fileName){
        def payload = new File(fileName).getText();
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(payload)

        vars.put("myVar",  object.event_id)

        return object.event_id
    }
}

  def running = new jmeter()
        running.parsingJSON( "C:/Users/payload.json")
```

this will return exception

`ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor Dummy
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: vars for class: jmeter`

But when I remove the class , so it looks like this

```js
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

    def parsingJSON(String fileName){
        def payload = new File(fileName).getText();
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(payload)

        vars.put("myVar",  object.event_id)

        return object.event_id
    }
    
        parsingJSON( "C:/Users/payload.json")
```

It will run without any issue.

My question: I understand `vars` is JMeter internal API , but can't we use `vars.put()` or `vars.get()` in Groovy script using `class{}` in JSR223 Sampler / PreProcessor in JMeter?

**[UPDATE after getting input 1 Jul 19]:**

I write the codes in Intellij and looks like this. It runs perfectly fine.

```js
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables


class jmeter {

    JMeterVariables vars;
    jmeter(JMeterVariables vars) {
        this.vars = vars;
    }

    def parsingJSON(String fileName){
        def payload = new File(fileName).getText();
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(payload)

        vars.put("myVar",  object.event_id)
        println("My Var " + vars.get("myVar"))

        return object.event_id
    }
}


class runTest {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        JMeterVariables vars = new JMeterVariables();
        def running = new jmeter(vars)
        running.parsingJSON( "C:/Users/payload")
    }
}
```

The code basically put the value to parameter myVar , so I can use it in my HTTP Request Sampler.
I copy paste it to JMeter JSR223 PreProcessor, then create HTTP Request sampler and put ${myVar} in the Body Data

[image]

I expect the value of "myVar" will be reflected in the Body Data. But after I run it , I see the parameter ${myVar} in Result Tree Listener , instead of the value.

[image]

**[UPDATE after getting input from Dmitry 3 July 2019]**

I use IntelliJ and write the code like this

```js
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables

class Global {
    static vars = [:]
}

Global.vars.jmeterVars = vars



class jmeter {

        def parsingJSON(String fileName){
        def payload = new File(fileName).getText();
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(payload)

        Global.vars.jmeterVars.put("myVar",  object.event_id)  //This will return java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method put() on null object
        println("My Var " + vars.get("myVar"))

        return object.event_id
    }
}


class runTest {
    static void main(String[] args) {

        def running = new jmeter()
        running.parsingJSON( "C:/Users/payload")

    }
}
```

This time even IntelliJ returns me an error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method put() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:34)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:135)
    at jmeter.parsingJSON(jmeter.groovy:21)
    at jmeter$parsingJSON.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
    at runTest.main(jmeter.groovy:38)`
  Basically, the error is caused by `Global.vars.jmeterVars.put("myVar",  object.event_id)`

**[UPDATE] : 17 July 2019 with input from user7294900**

I wrote the code like this in IntelliJ

```js
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables


class jmeter2 {

    JMeterVariables vars;

    jmeter2(JMeterVariables vars) {
        this.vars = vars;
    }

    public addvar(String VarName, String value) {
        vars.put(VarName, value);
    }


    def parsingJSON(String fileName) {
        def payload = new File(fileName).getText();
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(payload)

        addvar("myVar", object.event_id)
        println("My Var " + vars.get("myVar"))

        return object.event_id
    }
}


class runTest {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JMeterVariables vars = new JMeterVariables();
        def running = new jmeter2(vars)
        running.parsingJSON( "C:/Users/payload.json")

    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine in Intellij. I just need to add some jar dependencies to Intellij (`slf4j-simple-1.7.2` , `apachejmeter_core` , `logkit-1.2.2` ). IntelliJ will return the result. So far so good.

I copied paste the code to JMeter , by creating `JSR223 sampler` , `debug sampler` , and `Results Tree listener`.

I can't see any `myVar` created by JSR223 sampler in the Listener.

[image]

[image]

JMeter log also doesn't show any issue

`2019-07-17 12:33:15,806 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2019-07-17 12:33:15,806 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2019-07-17 12:33:15,812 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2019-07-17 12:33:15,812 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2019-07-17 12:33:15,812 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2019-07-17 12:33:15,812 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2019-07-17 12:33:15,813 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2019-07-17 12:33:15,813 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2019-07-17 12:33:15,813 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2019-07-17 12:33:15,825 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2019-07-17 12:33:15,825 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2019-07-17 12:33:15,825 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2019-07-17 12:33:15,825 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)`

The file ***payload.json*** only contains a very simple json

```js
{
"event_id": "01DE95CRARFQ4X9WEKXACQYHVX",
"event_type": "form_response"
}
```

I am not sure why JMeter doesn't like the script. 
Any idea maybe?   Thanks.

Comment: Did you try my answer? can you give feedback?

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't notice you modified your answer. I just give a try and have just updated the result in the thread above. Intellij is fine but JMeter still doesn't like it. Not sure why.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your code structure with minimal changes consider introducing a separate class holding static variables which will be accessible everywhere in your Groovy script.

Something like:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

class Global {
    static vars = [:]
}

Global.vars.jmeterVars = vars

class jmeter {


    def parsingJSON(String fileName) {

        def payload = new File(fileName).getText();
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(payload)

        Global.vars.jmeterVars.put("myVar", object.event_id)

        return object.event_id
    }
}

def running = new jmeter()
running.parsingJSON("C:/Users/payload.json")
```

More information:

- [Groovy Goodness: Variable Scope in Scripts](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-variable-scope-in.html)
- [Groovy: Object orientation](http://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html)
- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri , I just tried your idea and get an error. I updated the codes that I wrote and the error message in the main thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add variable(s) you need to pass current `JMeterVariables` object to jmeter object,

The following code add variable `aaa` to existing JMeter variables

```
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables;
class jmeter {
      JMeterVariables vars;
      jmeter(JMeterVariables vars) {
         this.vars = vars;
      }
public addvar() {
    vars.put("aaa","bbb");
}
}

def running = new jmeter(vars);
running.addvar();
```

So Intellij recognize `JMeterVariables` you will have to add `ApacheJMeter_core.jar` from JMeter's lib\ext folder